# Adding objects of a class to an ArrayList in another class

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

Im trying to add Objects of a Class called Student to an Arraylist in another class called StudentClass. I have initialised the list, but am having trouble working out how to add objects to the ArrayList

Code for StudentClass

```
public class StudentClass
{
   List<Student> studentList;
   private String studentName;
   private int lengthOfString;

   public StudentClass()
   {
      super();
      studentList = new ArrayList<>();
   }

 public void addStudent(String aName)
   {
     String objt = new String(name, mark);
     studentList.add(Student);
   }
```

Code for Student

```
public class Student
{

    private String name;
    private int mark;


    public Student(String aName)
    {
       super();
       this.name = aName;
       this.mark = -1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class StudentClass
  {
  List<Student> studentList;
  private String studentName;
  private int lengthOfString;

  public StudentClass()
  {
  super();
  studentList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addStudent(String aName) {
  Student student = new Student(aName);
  studentList.add(student);
  }      
  }

  public class Student
  {

  private String name;
  private int mark;

  public Student(String aName)
  {
  super();
  this.name = aName;
  this.mark = -1;   
  }
  }
```

I'm not clear what you're trying to do with the mark?

Comment: mark is being set as -1 initially to distinguish it from 0, then I will be writing a method to set the mark to whatever the students test result is at a later stage

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 public void addStudent(String aName) {
     studentList.add(new String(aName));
 }
```

Also, Student class constructor does not accept marks as second parameter, at least the code what you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your mistake is here:

```
 String objt = new String(name, mark);
 studentList.add(Student);
```

Write this instead:

```
 Student objt = new Student(name, mark);
 studentList.add(objt);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting "cannot find symbol - variable name"
Any thoughts?

Comment: @TreaureIsland, its because the parameter name is `aName` not `name`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `Student` object and then add that to your list:

```
public void addStudent(String aName) {
     Student student = new Student(aName);
     studentList.add(student);
}
```

It's not really clear from your provided code how the `mark` field is set, but either pass it through the `Student` construction and/or add getters and setters.